# Random number generator without replacement?

Tags: java, random

I have tried to program a *random number generator* that *doesn't generate the same random number more than once*. But I am unable to and can't figure out why. My code is like this at the moment:

```
public void printNS(){

    System.out.print("Numeros Numeros: ");

    for(int i=0; i < 5 ; i++){
        System.out.print( (int)(Math.random()*50) + ",");
    }

    System.out.print("; Numeros Stars: ");

    for(int i=0; i < 2 ; i++){
        System.out.print( (int)(Math.random()*12)+ ",");    
    }

}
```

Comment: can you use a set struct?

Comment: Generating true random numbers is much harder than you think it is...most are really pseudo random. https://www.random.org/

Comment: a simple solution is to store the number you have generated so that you can check whether there is a duplication later. but it comes with a cost of memory

Comment: Could you please be more clear and elaborate what is it that you are trying to ask !

Comment: Sure dude, what im trying to achive is that for example my out put is:

Numeros Numeros: 29,29,8,38,4; Numeros Stars: 7,8

I dont want numbers to repeat like 29 did

Comment: You can also try the Collections. Shuffle(array with 0-9).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in java 8 you can do the following

```
 int[] rand = new Random().ints(start, end).distinct().limit(number).toArray();
```

for more details/options see the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)

And before java 8 you can use a Set. Generate the random numbers until your set size is less than the desired number of random numbers

Answer (score 2):

So you want `k` distinct random numbers from `0` to `n` (with `k < n`).

Two possible approaches:

1. Pick `k` random numbers, as you already did, and store them in a data structure. Everytime you pick a number, check if it is already contained in the structure: if it is, keep picking until you have a "new" random number. It is a simple enough approach but the loop could potentially block your application. I suggest to use a `Set` since it stores distinct elements by definition

   ```
   Set<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<>(); // unordered
   while (set.size() < k){
      set.add((int)(Math.random()*n));
   }
   System.out.println(set);
   ```
2. Create a `List` and initialize it with every number between `0` and `n`. Then shuffle it. First `k` elements of the list are the numbers you want.

   ```
   List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(n);
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      list.add(i);
   }
   Collections.shuffle(list);
   list.subList(0, k).clear();
   System.out.println(list);
   ```

I would suggest the second approach as it is more clean, I don't know your efficiency requirements though.

Comment: Ok dude thanks a lot, look one more question is there any easyer way to randomly generate numbers like i did but simpler?

Comment: What do you mean? `Math.random()` looks simple enough to me

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
private printStars(int loops, int factor) {
  for(int i=0; i < loops ; i++){
    System.out.print( (int)(Math.random()*factor) + ",");
  }
```

And now:

```
public void printNS(){
  System.out.print("Numeros Numeros: ");
  printStars(5, 50);
  System.out.print("; Numeros Stars: ");
  printStars(2, 12);
```

Hope that helps. The key point is: when you have repeating code, look at those elements that are "identical"; and then move them into another method!