# Why does this program not stop duplicates in the array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to write a program that generates six random integers, and return them to the user without any of the numbers being duplicates. Why do duplicates still get through?

I've searched it up on Google and tried a few of the results, but none of them seemed to work. I thought of my own method to try to solve this issue, by doing the following:

Using a for loop, I store one number at a time from `drawnNums` (the array with six random numbers) in `numToCheck`. There is also a variable `numOfDuplicates` which stores how many of that number it found. Using another for loop, I go through all the numbers in `drawnNums` and compare it with `numToCheck`, and add one to `numOfDuplicates`. It obviously finds itself, so I have an if statement that only redraws numbers if `numOfDuplicates` is >= 2. This is in the same function where I create the array, so it should create a new array and check through again, redrawing until there are no duplicates.

In my mind, this should stop duplicates from being returned, but it doesn't.

This is from class I have created to generate the array, and what I described above.

```java
// Private function to draw one random number
    private int drawNumber() {
        return random.nextInt(maxNum) + 1;
    }

    // Function to randomly draw six numbers using drawNumber() and store in an array
    int[] draw() {
        int[] drawnNums = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        for (int i = 0; i < drawnNums.length; i++) {
            int draw = drawNumber();
            drawnNums[i] = draw;
        }

        // Check if there are any duplicates in the array, if there are, redraw
        int numOfDuplicates = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < drawnNums.length; x++) {
            int numToCheck = drawnNums[x];
            numOfDuplicates = 0;
             for (int y = 0; y < drawnNums.length; y++) {
                if (numToCheck == drawnNums[y]) {
                    numOfDuplicates++;
                }
                if (numOfDuplicates >= 2) {
                    draw();
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        return drawnNums;
    }
}
```

I expect that if there are duplicates in the array, the numbers will be redrawn until there is an array with no duplicates. But when running the program repeatedly, there are still some arrays with duplicates in them.

Comment: Maybe you want `return draw();` but I would think a better way would be the check the value before *adding* it to the array.

Comment: `for (int y = 1; y < drawnNums.length; y++) {`

Comment: there are many better ways to achieve what you are trying here, but the issue in your code is that `break;` you are breaking only after checking for duplicates for first element in the array.

Comment: Check for duplicates **before** you add the random value in **draw** to the **drawnNums** Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive call to draw is not returning a value. Should be

```
return draw();
```

The outer check loop exits early without completely checking the entire array for duplicates, remove the break. Check if x==y in the inner loop, do the duplicate check only if they are not.

Or in java 8, use a one liner to replace the entire thing.

```
new Random().ints(start, end).distinct().limit(number).toArray();
```

Ref - [Random number generator without replacement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43261147/random-number-generator-without-replacement)

Answer (score 1):

You want to check for duplicates within your returnable Array **before** you add to it. In other words, as soon as the **draw** variable receives a new random value see if that value is already contained within the **drawnNums** array:

```
private int[] draw() {
    int[] drawnNums = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    boolean alreadyHave;
    for (int i = 0; i < drawnNums.length; i++) {
        int draw = drawNumber();
        alreadyHave = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < drawnNums.length; j++) {
            if (draw == drawnNums[j]) {
                alreadyHave = true;
                i--;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!alreadyHave) {
            drawnNums[i] = draw;
        }
    }
    return drawnNums;
}
```

Comment: This method works in stopping duplicates from being added to the array, but it then just leaves the value at that index at 0, how would I draw another number in place of that and check it?

Comment: With the code before the last edit -- the outer loop could be ```for (int i; i<6; )```, and the ```if (!alreadyHave)``` clause would also increment i: ```drawnNums[i++] = draw```

Answer (score 0):

If you want uniqueness, it's easiest to use a container that gives you uniqueness.

```
int[] draw() {
    final int COUNT = 6;
    // get unique numbers
    Set<Integer> nums = new HashSet<>();
    while (nums.size() != COUNT)
        nums.add(drawNumber());
    // convert to array as per original requirements
    // though it would be simpler if we could just
    // return a Collection<Integer>
    int[] result = new int[COUNT];
    int k = 0;
    for (Integer num : nums)
       result[k] = num;
    return result;
}
```

Simpler, by a change of return type, with no loss of usefulness to the caller:

```
Collection<Integer> draw() {
    final int COUNT = 6;
    Set<Integer> nums = new HashSet<>();
    while (nums.size() != COUNT)
        nums.add(drawNumber());
    return nums;
}
```